# Avoiding repeated codes in each page asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, inheritance

I have developed a web site which has CRUD abilities at front pages and control panel as well. I see that I have written the same codes for each pages when trying to connect and CRUD.

I did not have enough time to research how to optimize my code and I have just written what I needed. I have suffered too. But I did not have another chance.

For example:

I have a db and of course I need a connection string. I need to read the records into the page (let's say) blogs.aspx.
In another page news.aspx I need to make a new connection again and I create a new Sqlconnection instance.

As I told, I have now more than 40 pages and there are lots of repeating db connection, datagridview populating codes.

**My questions:**

1. Would it be a good way to define Connection, DataTable, DataAdapter, Command instances in the master page (Site.Master)? Or would the encapsulation notion bar me?
2. If I wrote a class named as konnekt.cs how would I have inherited its objects to my current page? In other words how could I have extended to the konnekt.cs from my current page?

Maybe I will get negative votes, but I think this risk worths for learning these concepts.
I am a newbie on c# and also other programming languages.

Thanks for your tips.

Comment: what is "question eligible for bounty in 2 days"? Have I done something wrong?

Comment: No a bounty allows you to spend some of your rep to get an answer faster.  The person who answers it would get that additional "bounty" as an award.

Comment: Not having duplicated code is good. But decision on what is better for your particular case need to be done by you... Make change both ways - than revert one you don't like and commit another.

Comment: @ozkanozlu http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/213707

Comment: Thank you all JeremyMorehouse, Ramunas, AlexeiLevenkov

Comment: I think there's a design pattern for this, and Microsoft had something called the EnterpriseLibrary to take care of it (at least back in ASP.NET 2.0. I don't know if they've updated it or not)

Answer (score 5):

What you need to do is to learn the concept of "separation of concerns". Which basically means that you divide your code according to what it does. Right now (from what I've understood from your question), all your code is in one place. This, like you have noticed, is *not* a good thing. Sure it works now, but as soon as you need to make a modification you'll run into problems.

At its most basic you need to separate code that manipulates the data in the database (usually called a Data Access Layer) and the code that displays that data (Presentation Layer). When a page (Presentation layer) is loaded it calls the Data Access Layer to get the data from it (the page doesn't call the DB directly), and so on and so forth. Usually, there's a third layer between those two called a Business Layer that has the business rules logic.

**Would it be a good way to define Connection, DataTable, DataAdapter, Command instances in the master page (Site.Master)? Or would the encapsulation notion bar me?**

That's not a good idea. Master pages belong to the Presentation, so putting anything in there that calls the DB directly is a no go.

**If I wrote a class named as konnekt.cs how would I have inherited its objects to my current page? In other words how could I have extended to the konnekt.cs from my current page?**

Once again, never call the DB directly from your page. Construct another class that connects to the DB, and let the page call *that* class.

Answer (score 0):

You can define those method in other classes and just call them from code behind. Or define some of them in a common baseclass

2 you have to subclass page and then you can create your own baseclass

Answer (score 0):

Like [System Down](https://stackoverflow.com/users/196135/system-down), my suggestion discard the db code in pages code.. use App_Code folder.

In a page file code, you must be write the methods/properties/etc to do the page work, not db work.

For common page code, you can put it in a c# file (always under App_Code),

by extending `System.Web.UI.Page` class.

Example App_Code/PageBase.cs :

```
public class PageBase : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    // common code
}
```

Example Default.aspx.cs :

```
public partial class _Default : PageBase // instead of System.Web.UI.Page
{

}
```